# Threats about validation

Tags: windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do about counterfeit Windows warning](https://superuser.com/questions/23839/what-to-do-about-counterfeit-windows-warning)

Why should my laptop, (about three years old) now keep telling me that my copy of Windows does not pass Genuine Validation? I have been using regularly since I bought it some three or so years ago, all set up with Windows which I obviously purchased at the time.
The Laptop is a Gateway Laptop, bought from Tesco.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely, the Gateway OEM key was revoked. Re-activate using the COA sticker on the notebook.

Comment: @Revd Ken Sargeantson - what you may not know is that the key that was used to install Windows on your laptop is probably NOT the key printed on the sticker on the bottom (that's normal for OEMs). So it's likely that if you can re-activate with the sticker, you won't have a problem.

Comment: @MichaelKohne +1, I probably should've explained that.